# Spring 5 Reactor Netty log spam (too verbose)

Tags: spring, logging, netty, spring-webflux

Is there a way to reduce console/log noise output in Spring 5 + Reactor + Netty. It's too verbose, especially full print out of a request:

[image: Request printout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what helped me:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**src/main/resources/logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.sssXXX, UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger{15} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```